# How to automatically insert a class notation using eclipse templates?

Tags: java, eclipse, code-generation, eclipse-templates

Does anybody know how to insert a "@RunWith anotation" above the class signature, using eclipse templates?

Ex.:

```
@RunWith(Parameterized.class)
public class MyClassTest {
...
    @Parameters
    public static Collection<Object[]> parameters() {
        List<Object[]> list = new ArrayList<Object[]>();
        list.add(new Object[] { "mind!", "find!" });
        list.add(new Object[] { "misunderstood", "understood" });
        return list;
    }
...
}
```

__

Template:

```
// TODO: move this '@RunWith(Parameterized.class)' to class anotation
    @Parameters
    public static Collection<Object[]> parameters() {
        ${type:elemType(collection)}<Object[]> parametersList = new ${type:elemType(collection)}<Object[]>();
        ${cursor}// TODO: populate collection
        return parametersList;
    }
```

__ Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately, you cannot use Eclipse templates to add an annotation to an existing enclosing class (at least, not that I know of). However, there is a workaround. Here is a modified version of your template:

```
@${runnerType:newType(org.junit.runner.RunWith)}(${paramterizedType:newType(org.junit.runners.Parameterized)}.class)
public class ${primary_type_name} {
    @${parametersType:newType(org.junit.runners.Parameterized.Parameters)}
    public static ${collectionType:newType(java.util.Collection)}<Object[]> parameters() {
        ${baseCollectionType}<Object[]> parametersList = new ${concreteCollectionType}<Object[]>();
        ${cursor}// TODO: populate collection
        return parametersList;
    }
}
```

To use the template (assuming its named "Parameterized"):

1. Create a new class in Eclipse
2. Before doing anything else, select the stub class declaration, including the opening and closing braces.
3. Type the name of the template, and press `Cntrl+Space` to activate the template (you may have to select the template from the list of templates. I only have one template called Parameterized, so Eclipse just uses it automatically for me).

The class definition will be replaced with a definition that includes the `@RunWith` annotation. I used the **${*id*:newName(reference)}** template variable to cause Eclipse to automatically add all of the necessary imports (with the exception of the imports for `${baseCollectionType}` and the `${concreteCollectionType}`, you'll have to add those manually...thank goodness for `Cntrl-Shift-M`)

This is really hard to describe. You'll have to try it to see exactly how it works. Post a comment if my instructions need to be clarified.